# Can't find dkms.conf file when installing wifi driver rtl8812au

Tags: drivers, files, filesystem, icons, gedit

I am an old newbie who has got tired of Windows and migrated to Linux - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am trying to install a wifi driver for Netgear A6100. I have found a package for rlt88au but when installing it the process stops with the message:

```
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
```

The file exists but have a compressed-like file-icon. When trying to open it with gedit it says can't open PAK-files. It opens in nano and the first line is

```
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl8812AU"
```

Manipulating the content like inserting an empty line on top or removing the P in PACKAGE_NAME makes the file-icon change to txt-style. I tried to re-install with an inserted comment topline:

```
#
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl8812AU"
...
```

Now it found the file and didn't stop - not until the next problem! I feel like I'm back in Windows again.
Is it gedit, the system, the file-name or the file content that sets the file icon and lets the install procces find the file? Please help me understand!

Comment: Have you tried using the `rtl8812au-dkms` package from the repository that should automate all of this? In either case you should outline the steps you have taken already in a clear list including where you are getting the package/source and how you are trying to build it.

Comment: Thank you George for editing. It looks more understandable this way. And to Kristopher: as I'm totally new to Linux I'm more interested in learning the hokus-pokus with the file icons than actually install the driver. I think your solution with a clear list is good for me at the moment - I'm a bit confused right now.

Comment: The process of the icon is determined by MIME types, which effectively look at the contents of the file and compare it to known patterns then use that to determine the file type. For example you can run the command `file foobar` to see what type of a file `foobar` is. It will give you a human readable description of the file, but you can also pass the `--mime-type` flag to have it print the raw mime type which would be something like `text/plain` or `image/png` See [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) for a description of what they are and why they are formatted that way

Comment: Also there is the `mimetype` command. See [man mimetype](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mimetype.1p.html) for info too.

Comment: When installing a dkms driver from source, did you copy the source code folder to /usr/src with name of {module}-{version}?